# Jquery checkall/uncheck is not working properly?

Tags: jquery

```
  $(document).on('change', '#check-all', function() {

        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('.leads_checkbox').prop('checked','checked'); 
        } else {
            $('.leads_checkbox').removeProp('checked');
        }
    });
```

here is my code , which is checking all after click but not unchecking the checkboxes. please help.

Comment: I think it's caused by `:checked` not working as it should - can you share a HTML snippet?

Comment: which version of jQuey?

Comment: From the jquery documentation page of `removeProp` : Note: Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead.

Comment: Yeah, some more details or a Fiddle would help us to help you

Comment: `$('.leads_checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `prop` use `attr` which works fine for me.

**Updated code:**

```
$(document).on('change', '#check-all', function() {

    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('.leads_checkbox').attr('checked','checked'); 
    } else {
        $('.leads_checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
    }
});
```

**Demo:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwWqxm

**Update**

`attr` is failing in some scenario. I think you should stick with `prop`.

**Demo:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwWqxm

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple example of your issue

```
  $(document).on('change', '#check-all', function() {
       $('.leads_checkbox').prop('checked',$(this).is(":checked")); 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `removeProp("checked")` which doesn't work as expected because `checked` is a native propery of the element. You can see from the [**.removeProp()** documentation](https://api.jquery.com/removeProp/):

> Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected.

You should better reset the `checked` property as `false`:

```
$('.leads_checkbox').prop('checked', false);
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(document).on('change', '#check-all', function() {

        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('.leads_checkbox').prop('checked','checked'); 
        } else {
            $('.leads_checkbox').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Check All<input type="checkbox" id="check-all"/>
<br/><br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="leads_checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="leads_checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="leads_checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="leads_checkbox" />
```